# Proving $\int_0^1\int_0^1\chi_Sdxdy=0,$ while $\int_S\chi_S$ doesn't exist.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

> Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x\in\Bbb Q,0<x<1,\text{ and if } x=\frac{p}m,\gcd(p,m)=1,y=\frac{k}m,k=1,\ldots,m-1\}.\tag 1$

> Prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^1\chi_S dxdy=0$ while $\displaystyle \int_S\chi_S$ doesn't exist.

**My thoughts:**

I tried to write down $(1)$ differently, so I fixed some $y\in\Bbb Q.$ Then $y_0=\frac{p_0}{q_0},\gcd(p_0,q_0)=1.$ Then, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ all the points of the form $$\left(y_0,\frac{p}{q_0n}\right),\gcd(p,q_0n)=1,p<q_0n\tag 2$$ are in $S.$ I tried to show that the set of discontinuities of the function $$x\mapsto\begin{cases}1, &(x,y_0)\in S\\0,&(x,y_0)\notin S\end{cases}$$ is of measure zero and exactly the set $S$ and that the function $$y\mapsto\int_0^1\chi_Sdx$$ is non-zero on the set of the Jordan measure $0$. I thought I could prove that, for a given $y_0,$ the points in $(2)$ might form a discrete set,which would have a boundary of the Jordan measure zero, but I failed.

For the second integral, I thought one might argue that, even though, for some $x_0\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ there are only finitely many points $(x_0,y)\in S,$ since $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ is dense in $[0,1],$if we take a good enough subdivision of $[0,1]\times[0,1],$ letting $m\to\infty,$ there are infinitely many points from $S$ in a rectangle of the subdivision so the lower Darboux sum would equal $0,$ while the upper would be $1$ and therefore, $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]^2}\chi_S$ wouldn't exist, and neither would the given integral.

---

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track at all and what I've written seems messy even to me. Does anybody have any advice/hint on what to do?

Comment: There is a typo in the question where the double integral should be dy dx, not dx dy

Comment: @ChrisSanders, I could deal with that case, but is the claim of the question written false and could you elaborate it?

Comment: @ChrisSanders, except for the density, I wrote exactly that in my post. How do you prove that every open neighbourhood of every point in $(0,1)$ contains a point from the set $\{x\in(0,1):\chi_S(x,y_0)=1\}$?

Comment: @ChrisSanders, thank you! I see it now. Could you make that an answer so that the question is answered and so that I could accept it?

Comment: Answer made on it

Comment: @Chris, in 7 hours, I'll be able to click on the bounty button.

Comment: no problem, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the question where the double integral should be $dy\;dx$, not $dx\; dy$.

$\int_0^1\chi_S(x,y_0)dx$ does not exist for $y_0\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, because in such a case $S(x,y_0)=1$ if and only if $x$ is rational and the denominator of $x$ in lowest terms is a multiple of the denominator of $y_0$ in lowest terms.

Therefore for $y_0\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, the sets $\{x\in(0,1):\chi_S(x,y_0)=1\}$ and $\{x\in(0,1):\chi_S(x,y_0)=0\}$ are both dense in $(0,1)$.

$\\$

**Elaboration, on OP's request, of why the first set is dense:**

Let's say $y_0=\frac{n}{m}\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, where $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$.

For any small interval $I\subset(0,1)$, choose $k$ large enough so that when you look at the points $\frac{j}{m^k}$ for $1\leq j\leq m^k-1$, at least $m$ of these points are in $I$. So the interval $I$ contains $\frac{j}{m^k},\frac{j+1}{m^k},\ldots,\frac{j+m-1}{m^k}$, where at least one of $j,j+1,\ldots,j+m-1$ is $1\,\text{mod}(m)$, which we could call $j'$. Now $\frac{j'}{m^k}$ is in its simplest form, and $m^k$ is a multiple of $m$, so $\frac{j'}{m^k}$ is in $\{x\in(0,1):\chi_S(x,y_0)=1\}$